# How to align a picture beside <h1> HTML

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to create a logo picture next to my title on my website.

Problems:

- Works with Span
- Span is too small
- Doesn't work with H1 - H6

Could anyone help me?

Here is my code.

```css
    .title img {
        vertical-align:middle;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="title">
        <h1><b>Ex</b><i>Creations</i></h1>
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="ExCreations logo." width="100px" height="100px">
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="../"><b>Ex</b><i>Creations</i></a>
            <a href="../Projects"><i>Current Projects</i></a>
            <a href="../error/sitemap">Site <b>Map</b></a>
            <a href="../Questions"><i>Have any questions?</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

But it doesn't work. Although it does with span. Could anyone fix this but keep the h1?

Comment: H tags have a built in line break. Is there any reason you don't want to use spans?

Comment: It's too small. I really would like to use an **H1**. So is it not possible?

Comment: You can use a span and use CSS to make it look like H tag

Comment: You should not choose elements based on “how big” they are with default formatting applied, but on how well the are suited to structure the content. And if anything is “too big/small” – then _format_ it with CSS to your liking, that’s what it’s _for_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because h1 has 100% width, add the following CSS code:

```
.title h1 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked! I can't accept the answer yet though. I will in 10 minutes

Answer (score 2):

`h1` is a **block-level** element (therefore the `img` wraps into a "new line").

Instead place your `<img>` tag inside the `<h1>`

```
<div class="title">
    <h1>
       <b>Ex</b><i>Creations</i>
       <img src="http://s8.postimg.org/9znb8gixh/logo.png" alt="ExCreations logo." width="100px" height="100px">
    </h1>
</div>
```

than you can use any `vertical-align` value for the Logo using

```
.title h1 img{
   vertical-align: middle; /*https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align*/
}
```

SEO-wise it's also nice to have an image with `alt` "Logo" inside the primary `H1`